# Can someone please explain the Outcome of the following code in java

Tags: java

Can someone please explain the outcome of the following code, or at least tell me the documentation i need to read in order to understand it.

*I am a beginner with some very basic/little knowledge of java.*

**Here is the code :**

```
class A {
    public int key;
    public void f() { key=key+1; }
}
class B extends  A {
    public void f() { key = key+10; }
}

public class Problem1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B P= new B();
        P.key = 0;
        A Q = P;
        A R = new A();
        R.key = 8;
        P.f();
        Q.f();
        R.f();
        System.out.println(P.key);
        System.out.println(Q.key);
        System.out.println(R.key);
    }

}
```

**Outcome:**

```
20
20
9
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you try to debug it

Comment: I strongly recommend learning to use a debugger.  Then you'll be able to step through this code, and see exactly what's going on inside each of the three objects that you created.

Comment: Thank you, i will try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make this question clear, I suggest you to read about Java [Reference/Object](http://www.kdgregory.com/index.php?page=java.refobj) & [method override](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html) first.

---

Below are the description of every steps in your code:

1. You create a new instance of Class"B" and a reference P pointing to it:
   [image]
2. You create anoher reference Q and also pointing to above object:
   **But pay attention, the method `f()` in B overrided `f()` in A.**
   [image]
3. You create a new instance of Class"A" and a reference R pointing to it:
   [image]
4. So, you have totally 2 objects(one for Class B and one for Class A) and 3 references now. **Below code call B's f() 2 times, A's f() 1 times.** So the result is:
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

So this looks like a very basic example of inheritance, the parent class being "A"

```
      public int key;
```

this is called a Field, which is just a variable inside a class. The next line is a function

```
      public void f() { key=key+1; }
```

This is a method that can be used on A objects. When you call f(), it will increment our variable 'key'

The next class is a child function of A, we know this because of the "extends" keyword. When a class is a child function, it has all of the same functions (hence the term inheritance), plus some more of its own. This means that an object of type B will have a field called key because that's what its parent class has.

In class B, there is another method f() that increments key by 10. Notice that the method f() is overloaded, which means that two methods within a class have the same name, but different, implicitly defined parameters. So if you call f() an object of type A, it will increment key by one, and if you call it with an object of type B, it will increment key by 10.

```
       public class problem1{
```

tests out the data types A and B. Knowing this, try to trace the output of problem1.

Comment: Thank you for explaining, it makes a lot of sense now. I will, however, read Reference/Object and method override as someone suggested.